# Gmail is not accepting my Hotmail password for POP3

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, pop3

I've just changed my Hotmail password, however, when I try to update Gmail I get the following error:

> Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
>
> Please contact Microsoft's Support Team for more information on POP access.

I don't have 2FA enabled so it's not that. Any ideas what it could be please? It accepts the same password for SMTP, it's just the POP servers having the problem.

I'm using `pop-mail.outlook.com` on port 995.

POP is enabled under Options -> Mail -> Accounts -> POP and IMAP